# Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) crash on right click each time

Tags: windows, windows-7, explorer

I have a problem with explorer.exe, keeps crashing each time on right click and every couple of minutes.

Trying a lot of fixes in regedit and nothing :(

Installed a new Windows 7 and now it's the same.

How to fix that?

Comment: This is not a question relating to software development; try one of the other StackExchange sites instead.

Comment: Does it crash with a fresh Windows 7? No applications installed? Clean hard drive? Otherwise check your RAM for integrity.

Comment: Not on a fresh one..only after i install all softwares/drivers/etc

Comment: You've probably installed a bogus shell extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a registry windows problem...You should go to

"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ ContextMenuHandlers" in regedit.exe, backing up the whole ConxtentMenuHandlers folder, and then start deleting all of them one by one  and continuously testing the right click.

Generally the issue is fixed by erasing this registry entry :

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\BriefcaseMenu]
@="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

Comment: Deleted. I have only open with, sharing and pin to taskbar. Now I can't search to start menu and everyting is working slow :(

Comment: U DIDN't tell US that things are slow in your PC...Can u open windows task manager????...(CTRL + ALT + SUPPR)

Comment: I can use all softwares, but I when I type into start search i get nothing. here you can see how it's crashing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPGD9CeEd9M

Comment: Now I can search - dunno why, but same problem with crashing.

Comment: Can you restore your pc to a previous date where everything was OK...   It's possible in Win 7

Comment: after restore it's a bit better, i don't get crashes each time ..but i still get them

Comment: Try running from an Elevated "Command Prompt" (running as administrator) "sfc /scannow" If there are any corrupt files this will repair them ... No Quotes and space after sfc...

Comment: windows resource protection did not found any integrity violations.

Comment: This actually worked. I deleted them one by one and eventually found the offending folder. Thank you!